# Money management for every profitable 3rd trade

Tags: money-management

What would be the best money management strategy if I know that approximately every 3rd trade is profitable. What is the best MM strategy?

Comment: What about the other 2 trades? Can you tell us a bit more about the distribution of the expected profit?

Comment: Skip trades 1 + 2!

Comment: On average, one-in-three trades were profitable? Or every third-or-so trade on the same asset was profitable? (ie an Expo/Poisson problem). With what profit if right and loss if not?

Comment: One possibility is that you monitor every trade, but you enter the trade with real money only if the past trade (or past 2 trades) would have made a loss. This attempts to take advantage of negative correlation between the outcomes of successive trades.

Comment: @noob2 hm, now this is pretty obvious. Just to enter a trade after trades with a loss. I think I should take a rest :)